# NSIS close running instance of net program to install

Tags: c#, winforms, mutex, nsis, findwindow

I have done this before with MFC programs without a problem because I could set the class name. This is a no go with net except through a hack.

I cannot use the window title either because it is decorated. So FindWindow seems to be out of the question.

The net program uses a mutex to ensure single instance and I can get NSIS to detect it. However, I cannot get NSIS to tell the running instance to close from this.

So, any suggestions? Thanks people.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least three NSIS plugins that let you close processes:

- [Processes_plug-in](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Processes_plug-in)
- [KillProc](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/KillProc_plug-in)
- [NsProcess](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NsProcess_plugin)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm aware of those but couldn't make them work with [link](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Check_whether_your_application_is_running#Using_a_Win32_Synchronization_Object) because the mutex does not yield a unique handle to the program and the executable name might not be unique either.